# Уязвима ли OpenSSH для Shellshock (CVE-2014-6271)

Tags: уязвимости, ssh, bash

24 сентября 2014 в [блоге RedHat](https://securityblog.redhat.com/2014/09/24/bash-specially-crafted-environment-variables-code-injection-attack/) появилось сообщение о критической уязвимости в BASH, которую вскоре назвали Shellshock. Об этой уязвимости есть статья в [OpenNet](http://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=40667), где, в частности, приводится пример использования уязвимости против SSH.

> В случае с OpenSSH атака может быть проведена через подстановку переменной
> окружения `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND`:

```
   ssh -o 'rsaauthentication yes' remotehost '() { ignored; }; /usr/bin/id'
```

> После выполнения указанной команды в переменную окружения будет скопирована
> в том числе строка `'() { ignored; }; /usr/bin/id'`, которая инициирует
> запуск команды `/usr/bin/id` на стороне удалённой системы.

Как можно понимать этот пример, ведь запуск BASH на стороне удаленной системы выполняется после авторизации, то есть пользователь и так имеет право выполнить `/usr/bin/id` (и любую другую команду) на стороне удаленной системы?